# Can't convert Json

Tags: c#, json

I convert String to json. But how convert it to String?

```
String memb ="Hello 'test' From TestController! \r\n";
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
memb = serializer.Serialize(memb);//memb="\"\\\"Hello \\\\u0027test\\\\u0027 From Test Controller! \\\\r\\\\n\\\"\""
```

How convert (deserialize) to string?
P.S. It project in Console and I have problem reference library `using System.Web.Extensions`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize("string here"); //to json
string str = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(string)).ToString(); //to string
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use **Newtonsoft**.

Steps:

1. Download the from this link: http://json.codeplex.com/
2. Add reference Newtonsoft.Json.dll
3. add using in the relevant file: `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

Then you can use it as following:

```
String memb = "Hello 'test' From TestController! \r\n";
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(memb);
String deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<String>(output);
```